# Objective-C: How to correctly initialize char[]?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, initialization, char

I need to take a char [] array and copy it's value to another, but I fail every time.

It works using this format:

`char array[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }`

However, when I try to do this:

```
char array[] = char new_array[];
```

it fails, even though the new_array is just like the original.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please back up a step and explain why you want to copy char arrays.

Comment: @Mike, the original char array[] get's populated during a loop with other values. After the loop ends I need to set it up to the next char new_array[] value. Since I'm not able to do that (yet) it starts the next loop with the wrong values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy at runtime, the usual C method is to use the `strncpy` or `memcpy` functions.

If you want two `char` arrays initialized to the same constant initializer at compile time, you're probably stuck with using `#define`:

```
#define ARRAY_INIT { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }
char array[] = ARRAY_INIT;
char new_array[] = ARRAY_INIT;
```

Thing is, this is rarely done because there's usually a better implementation.

**EDIT:** Okay, so you want to copy arrays at runtime. This is done with `memcpy`, part of `<string.h>` (of all places).

If I'm reading you right, you have initial conditions like so:

```
char array[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
char new_array[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0xFF };
```

Then you do something, changing the arrays' contents, and after it's done, you want to set `array` to match `new_array`. That's just this:

```
memcpy(new_array, array, sizeof(array));
/*        ^         ^          ^
          |         |          +--- size in bytes
          |         +-------------- source array
          +-------------------------destination array
 */
```

The library writers chose to order the arguments with the destination first because that's the same order as in assignment: `destination = source`.

There is no language-level built-in means to copy arrays in C, Objective-C, or C++ with primitive arrays like this. C++ encourages people to use `std::vector`, and Objective-C encourages the use of `NSArray`.

I'm still not sure of exactly what you want, though.

Comment: char array[] is { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, however char new_array[] is diffent, such as { 0x01, 0x00, 0xFF } — so i can't really define it like that. Is there maybe way to 'reset' it's = defined value, so after loop one it would take on the next default value?

Comment: thank you very much — that's definitely helpful information; i've been going around and around with this trying to figure out why things weren't exactly making sense. How should sizeof(array) be represented? i think this will work, although getting 'unrecognized selector' error now. it looks like it crashes right on `__len size_t` `__memcpy_chk` i think it might be trying to go from void * to const void * [thanks!]

Comment: It's dang near impossible to help you at this point without some code cut-and-paste.

Comment: without a doubt you've helped me out. the code is incredibly long, so trying to post it here might not work. if you want me to upload the project somewhere i can, just let me know.

Comment: Standard procedure is to make a copy of your project yourself, then cut parts out of it until you have the smallest program that reproduces the behavior, then post that. So, for example, in this case, if you have a for loop with a lot of stuff in it, but the important part is that it modifies `array`, you could replace most of it with a few lines that change part or all of `array`.

Comment: hi mike, everything is working now. i figured out that trying to call memcpy from a method like `[self gotoMemcopyMethod]` while inside the loop it seems to have no effect. it took alot of trial and error, but your suggestions were definitely key. ;-) one last question -- what should sizeof(arrary) be in this case (i'm guessing 3), i did it like `sizeof(new_bytes)` and get a warning, but it works. thanks again!

Comment: `sizeof(array)` only works if `array` is an actual array (i.e. declared like `char array[15];`; it won't work with pointers (it will just give the pointer's size), in which case you have to get the array size by some other means. Usually we pass the array size with the array pointer to any function that needs it. Again, without seeing the code, I can't say anything specific.